# I want to write rspec test using factory girl for a particular usecase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, attributes, factory-bot

My usecase is to build a http request with content type as json. for example i hit an endpoint with post call with basic authentication(authentication is Basic Auth could be like id: bla , key: blabla) and the body is for example:

`{
   "age":"Name",
   "properties":{
         "age":21}
}`

and have to check response code and response message.
Sometimes i dont want to include age(mandatory field internally) to see if the proper status code is returned. 
I want to write my tests in such a way that it should look like:

```
it 'some test' do
    response = create(:event)
    expect(response.code).to eq(200)
  end
```

the above test should make an http call and return response to assert.
I am totally confused how to create a factory for the above scenario. I am an amateur with Rspec .

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters to perform POST action, based on response status code you can assert whether api call is success or not?

You cannot use factorygirl here.

for example:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "Widget management", :type => :request do

  it "creates a Widget" do
    headers = {
      "ACCEPT" => "application/json",     # This is what Rails 4 accepts
      "HTTP_ACCEPT" => "application/json" # This is what Rails 3 accepts
    }
    post "/widgets", { :widget => {:name => "My Widget"} }, headers

    expect(response.content_type).to eq("application/json")
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
  end

end
```

refer: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/
for rspec

Comment: My request: `curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic dGVzdEFwcDp0ZXN0S2V5" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -d '{
   "age":"Name",
   "properties":{
         "age":21}
}
}' "http://ab.xyz.com"`. My response will be like `{
  "accepted": true,
  "_itemId": "133b1921-b569-4b32-9645-26d8e46736c4"
}` with status code 200 . i have to check if the status code is 200 . I have to write test using factory girl.

Comment: A request spec should make real requests. But you can mock the responses. This answer is a good start -- if you add VCR to your project, you can configure it to return a recorded response for a request. See https://github.com/vcr/vcr